# Manual byte[] input to SQL Server

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

On the SQL Server, there is a column in a table of the type `Byte[]` from the .Net Framework.

I want to add data manually as the volume isn't big and I don't want to create a function for test data.

This is the **error** i get when i try to enter data.

```
The changed value in this cell was not recognized as valid. .NET
Framework Data Type: Byte[]
```

What is the input type for `Byte[]`?

Comment: First of all, T-SQL does not have the type `byte[]`, it has `[VAR]BINARY(<length>/MAX)`. Values for these types take the form `0x....`, per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#binary-constants). A simple way to generate non-constant binary values is to use `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(x)`, which produces `x` random bytes. On the .NET end, on the other hand, there are no constants of type `byte[]`, but you can use array initializers (in C#, `var b = new byte[] { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56 }`).

Comment: So there is no way to enter data manually?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "manually". If you mean "using the 'Edit top X rows' interface of SQL Server Management Studio", as I suspect you do, then the answer appears to be "no", unless you want to get really complicated with triggers on a view that convert string data to binary data on the fly. (My version of SSMS, 18.1, helpfully says "You cannot use the Result pane to set this Field data to values other than NULL.") This is not worth bothering with; you can use SMSS to generate `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements for the table.